# Multiply Variable by Another Variable?

Tags: c, calculator

I have a program for a C class I need to write. The program asks for a quantity, and I need to multiply that quantity by another variable which the user inputs. Basic calculator script for a c class :)

I have it set up like this,

```
    int qty; //basic quantity var
float euro, euro_result;

//assign values to my float vars
euro = .6896; //Euro Dollars
    euro_result = euro * qty; // Euro Dollars multiplied by user input qty

//start program for user
printf("Enter a quantity: ");

//alow user to input a quantity
scanf("%d", &qty);

printf("Euro:       %f \n", euro_result);
```

Why does it not work as expected?

Comment: I can't see a question here. I have edited it to reflect its real status.

Comment: Just a comment..remember to initialize the variable as you define them. so that it becomes easier to debug. For example, instead of doing int qty; define it as int qty = 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiply the euro with user given quantity qty before entered by the user.
It should be as below:
    //euro_result = euro * qty; // <-- shift this to the position given below

```
//start program for user
printf("Enter a quantity: ");

//alow user to input a quantity
scanf("%d", &qty);

euro_result = euro * qty; // Euro Dollars multiplied by user input qty

printf("Euro:       %f \n", euro_result);
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 7):

The bug is that the line

```
euro_result = euro * qty;
```

needs to be after qty is read-in

Answer (score 7):

The statements in a C program are **executed sequentially**, and expressions are **not evaluated symbolically**. So you need to reorder your statements this way:

```
int qty;
float euro, euro_result;

euro = .6896; // store constant value in 'euro'

printf("Enter a quantity: ");

scanf("%d", &qty); // store user input in 'qty'

euro_result = euro * qty; // load values from 'euro' and 'qty',
                          // multiply them and store the result
                          // in 'euro_result'

printf("Euro:       %f \n", euro_result);
```

Comment: Ah! So put it after the user has selected the qty and it should work. DUH! I am so stupid I did not even think of that.

Comment: Don't worry. It's a common beginner's mistake.

Comment: a beginner? What gave it away? :)

Comment: It's a common beginner's reaction to think they're stupid :-)

Comment: is it ok for me to post my finished code on here to have people critique? if not is there an ideal location on the web? i am always seeking gurus to lend me their five minutes...

Comment: Go ahead. You can always edit your question to add more information or to show us your finished code. Just don't post it as an answer. And if you have a follow-up question, feel free to open another question.

Comment: yep, it's common when you come from lisp

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to calculate `euro_result = euro * qty;` only *after* you have gathered the value for qty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're multiplying the `qty` by the exchange rate before the user has inputted any data.